# Full script not running when onFormSubmit Triggered but will work manually with onEdit()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gs-installable-triggers

```
function BatteryInspection(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn()
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  Logger.log("The row is " + row + " and column is " + col + " the sheet is " + sheet);

  var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize;

  var sheetName, colToCapitalize;
  colToCapitalize = 2;
  sheetName = "FormResponses1";
  if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.range.columnStart !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == "object") return;
  e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());

  sheet.getRange(row, 10).setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B" + row + ",\" \",\"\")");

  var cellcopy = sheet.getRange(row, 10);
  var cellvalues = cellcopy.getValues();

  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValues(cellvalues);
  cellcopy.clearContent();

  sheet.getRange(row, 8).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,2,0)");
  sheet.getRange(row, 9).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,3,0)");
}
```

The outcome I want is that the above script runs when a new row of data is added from a google form to the worksheet "FormResponses1". I have created the google form already, and new data is added to the sheet "FormResponses1" when a user submits the form.

[Here is a YouTube video of the screen showing the problem I'm having](https://youtu.be/oTigM3Km39Y)

The above code runs fine and does what I need if I manually add a new value to a cell e.g. if I write "dll 463" in cell "B2" on sheet "FormResponses1".

I have set up a trigger "From spreadsheet - On form submit" for the function onEdit shown above, using Edit - Current project's triggers from the toolbar in the <> script editor view.

The trigger does seem to fire, and if I view the logs after submitting a new response from the form, I can see the log shows the row and column that got edited via the Logger.log line in the code above.

I have added more Logger.log lines to the above code to see how far the script runs when it is triggered by the "From spreadsheet - On form submit" trigger, but no other logs are shown after the row and column edit log.

What makes this more weird for me, is that I could get the trigger to work and run the code yesterday. Albeit, it was only writing in the setFormula lines at the end of the current script, and since then I have added the capitalise column values, and substitute formula to the script.

I have tried:
- Deleting and adding a new trigger.
- Creating a new version 
- Deleting form repsonses
- Changing the function from onEdit() to onFormSubmit()
- Unlinking the spreadsheet and adding a new spreadsheet (with the same sheet names and data) with the script copied into the new spreadsheet script editor and deleting the old spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome. It is counter-intuitive that you might have a trigger for both onEdit as well as onFormSubmit. The code that you have supplied is useful but it is also a red-herring because you haven't explained the problem that you are trying to solve and the difficulties that you are having doing so. Would you please edit your question to explain your scenario and the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, I have edited my question, hopefully it makes my issue a bit clearer. If you have any other questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: The trigger that you want is `onFormSubmit` This is an installable trigger that runs when a user responds to a form. As the name suggests you MUST "install" it. Manual installation is easiest [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).  I reckon this will fix the problem.

Comment: Is this not what I have done when I set the trigger up using Edit - Current project's triggers and then + Add Trigger, or is there something I have to edit in the script itself?

Comment: FYI-triggers can be Simple or Installable. A "Simple" `onEdit` script (which is what you have) cannot be triggered by a script event (such as the form submission). [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). Note I stressed a "Simple" `onEdit` - that's because `onEdit` can also be an Installable trigger. "Simple" triggers have predefined names (onOpen, onEdit, etc) and that's all it takes to create the trigger. But an Installable trigger can have any name at all - it is in the process of installation that one identifies the script name and the event type.

Comment: OK, I changed the script name to BatteryInspection and deleted the old on Form Submit trigger. I then created the new on Form Submit trigger and assigne dthe BatteryInspection script. When a new row is added from the form submit, the BatteryInspection script runs, but again it doesn't seem to get any further than the Logger.log line to see which row and column was edited, and this does show the correct row and column number

Comment: Yes, I have done this through the Edit - Current Project's Triggers view

Comment: I have added .getName() and the log displays row and column number and shett name as "Sheet" [20-01-11 14:01:50:366 GMT] The row is 10 and column is 1 the sheet is Sheet

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having (besides the code you wrote is also a little messy) is that when an event is triggered by an "On edit" or by an "On form submit", the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) are different for them, therefore they will not have the same properties and you can apply the same logic as you were doing in your code.

This is how an [Edit Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) looks like and this is how a [Form submit Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) looks like.

Knowing that. I modified your code in the following way:

In your main function, I check what is the cause of the trigger, if it's an edit or a submit event, then depending on the event and if the conditions for both of them are true, I call the `onEditChange` or `onSubmitChange` functions.

```
function BatteryInspection(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var colToCapitalize = 2;
  var sheetName = "FormResponses1";
  // Let's see if it is a form or edit object, checking the namedValues properties
  if(!e.namedValues){
    // Edit event
    // Check the right conditions for an edit event
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || row < 2 || col !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == "object") return;
    else onEditChange(e, sheet, row);
  } else {
    // Submit Event
     // Check the right conditions for a submit event
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || row < 2 | typeof e.values != "object") return;
    else onSubmitChange(e, sheet, row);
  }
}
```

Inside the `onEditChange` and `onSubmitChange` functions, I set the values in the right cell to uppercase and then call the `setFormulas` function.

```
// Call when there is an edit event 
function onEditChange(evt, sheet, row){
  // Uppercase the value where the triggered occured
  evt.range.setValue(evt.value.toUpperCase());
  setFormulas(sheet, row);
}

// Call when there is an submit event 
function onSubmitChange(evt, sheet, row){
  // Uppercase the value just in the value of the second col
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(evt.values[1].toUpperCase());
  setFormulas(sheet, row);
}
```

In the  `setFormulas` function as the name indicates, I just set the formulas that you were setting previously in your main function `BatteryInspection`.

```
// Function for setting the formulas
// Call whether an edit or submit event happens
function setFormulas(sheet, row){
  sheet.getRange(row, 10).setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B" + row + ",\" \",\"\")");
  var cellcopy = sheet.getRange(row, 10);
  var cellvalues = cellcopy.getValues();
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValues(cellvalues);
  cellcopy.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(row, 8).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,2,0)");
  sheet.getRange(row, 9).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,3,0)");
}
```

The whole code now would look like this:

```
function BatteryInspection(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var colToCapitalize = 2;
  var sheetName = "FormResponses1";
  // Let's see if it is a form or edit object, checking the namedValues properties
  if(!e.namedValues){
    // Edit event
    // Check the right conditions for an edit event
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || row < 2 || col !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == "object") return;
    else onEditChange(e, sheet, row);
  } else {
    // Submit Event
     // Check the right conditions for a submit event
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || row < 2 | typeof e.values != "object") return;
    else onSubmitChange(e, sheet, row);
  }
}

// Call when there is an edit event 
function onEditChange(evt, sheet, row){
  // Uppercase the value where the triggered occured
  evt.range.setValue(evt.value.toUpperCase());
  setFormulas(sheet, row);
}

// Call when there is an submit event 
function onSubmitChange(evt, sheet, row){
  // Uppercase the value just in the value of the second col
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(evt.values[1].toUpperCase());
  setFormulas(sheet, row);
}

// Function for setting the formulas
// Call whether an edit or submit event happens
function setFormulas(sheet, row){
  sheet.getRange(row, 10).setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B" + row + ",\" \",\"\")");
  var cellcopy = sheet.getRange(row, 10);
  var cellvalues = cellcopy.getValues();
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValues(cellvalues);
  cellcopy.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(row, 8).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,2,0)");
  sheet.getRange(row, 9).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(B" + row + ",LookUpTable!A2:C1001,3,0)");
}
```

### Docs

For more info, you can also check:

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [Installable Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)